# Notify customer service representative the source of the call

Tags: twilio

Our company has dozens of web sites selling a diverse set of products under various brand names, but one call center for everything. Some of our services are cross-sold between web sites and it can be confusing for customers who are calling and expecting to be greeted by one company, but instead are greeted by someone from a "different" company.

I think Twilio could solve this problem for us.

Would it be possible to set up unique numbers for each web site and when the call gets answered at our call center, Twilio verbally states the web site to the CSR BEFORE connecting the caller? In this way, the CSR knows which "company" to "be from".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Yup, you can totally do that using Twilio.  The API allows you to buy new numbers on the fly (or you can buy them manually via the portal), so you could store each number in a database, associate it with a specific service, and just assign each number the same voice URL.

When a customer calls one of those numbers Twilio is going to make an HTTP request to the URL assigned to that number and as part of that request is going to pass a bunch of parameters including the phone number that the customer called.  You can use this parameter to look up in your database the associated service and then use Twilios whisper capability to tell the Agent the name of the service the customer is calling before they get connected to the customer.

Hope that helps.